# Shall I worry about these cracks in wall?

Tags: walls, uk, cracks

I have a few small cracks in different places in the house. Most of them around doors and windows and they are horizontal or vertical, which I think they are pretty common and nothing to worry about.

But I also have these ones in one of the walls of the staircase, coming from the ceiling - the loft/roof is in the other side. I have read that when they look like this maybe worth to check.

I cannot see anything similar anywhere else in the house

It is an old brick house (1900ish) in the UK, it was converted to house recently (5 years or so) and it had new building warranty etc.

I was thinking on calling my insurance to check it out, but I would really appreciate some advice.

[image]

Comment: Is that a plaster wall? I ask because it looks “thick” where the cracks are, possibly from stair vibrations.

Comment: Good point. It may be just paint on top of the brick. Definitively sounds solid. So I guess no plaster wall. I thought it may have had a cover in plaster...

Comment: Edited the question to remove references to plaster @EdBeal

Comment: As the crack is lazy not following a straight line or stair step pattern I would guess at a fast over coat with gypsum mud or what is used for Sheetrock, the thickness of the cracks or how they look could be from changes in temperature especially if on an outside wall. I don’t think I would be concerned at this point.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about this one, unless it both propagates and becomes wider. Do keep an eye on it regardless of this though.

Comment: "converted to house recently" …what was it before? Do you have neighbours with similar properties? If so, ask them if they have similar movement. Victorian houses don't have solid foundations like new builds, so have a tendency to shift over time, depending on what the ground is like underneath. 5 years isn't enough to really see a historical shift vs a new one.

Comment: Thanks @EdBeal and MiG. I will try to cover it and keep and eye on it

Comment: @Tetsujin not sure what was originally - coach house probably (it is part of a set of buildings that use to be in a bigger manor grounds - stables, coach house ...) For the las 20 years or so they were used as offices, the converted recently to houses

Comment: Ah, OK - then you'll probably have to wait & see. Just keep an eye on it, it's fine right now.